# Failed to parse input string datetime in BQ MySQL

Tags: mysql, date, datetime, parsing, google-bigquery

I have a datetime column in my table, the values look like this:

```
datetime
2009/03/04 11:06:29
2009/06/05 09:22:13
2009/07/05 09:24:43
```

The desired output is:

```
datetime
2009-03-04 
2009-06-05 
2009-07-05
```

I have tried the following:

```
PARSE_DATETIME('%m/%d/%Y', datetime) AS datetime
```

It gave me an error: `Failed to parse input string 2009/03/04 11:06:29`

Comment: You might try something like `DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(your_date_field, '%Y/%d/%m %H:%i:%s'), '%m/%d/%Y')`. Demo - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a7abdf/8/0 An existing date format - `%Y/%d/%m %H:%i:%s`, a new format - `%m/%d/%Y`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [left](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/string_functions#left):

```
select left(datetime, 10) from mytable
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a datetime column already, so you don't need to parse it. Parsing is for when you have a string input and you want to convert it to a datetime.

You need to use [FORMAT_DATETIME()](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/datetime_functions#format_datetime) to format the column, and you need to use a format string that matches what you want.

```
SELECT FORMAT_DATETIME('%Y/%m/%d', datetime) ...
```

Comment: Got an error: `No matching signature for function FORMAT_DATETIME for argument types: STRING, STRING. Supported signatures: FORMAT_DATETIME(STRING, DATETIME); FORMAT_DATETIME(STRING, TIMESTAMP, [STRING])`

Comment: Sounds like your datetime column is not a datetime _data type_.